# UIPopoverController passthroughViews ignoring Z-index and hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipopovercontroller

With iOS7 tables has extended edges that lies under navigation bar, tabbar, etc. When I presenting UIPopoverController from one of cells of that table and set that table in the passthroughViews, it causes possible to tap on the cell *under navigation bar, toolbar, tabbar, whatever! Even if bars are upper than tableview.*

When I confronted this with UISearchBar, I've set up passthroughViews like that

```
@[self.searchBar, self.tableView]
```

(no matter that searchbar is in tableHeaderView) and everything was working fine (I thought). But now I know it's definitely an unexpected behaviour, possibly a bug in Cocoa Touch.

Have anyone solved this?